# One gedit instance per i3 workspace

Tags: i3, window, gedit

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, I get one gedit window (or even instance?) per workspace. Opening a new file, e.g. from Nautilus, would open it in a new tab in the workspace window, or open a new one if there was none.

With i3, all files are opened as new tabs in a *single* window (the one last in focus, if there are multiple). This is not a good fit for my workflows; I like to have several windows open in parallel, on different workspaces, for different purposes.

While I can certainly

- navigate to the gedit window the file opened in,
- move the tab to a new window,
- move the new window to the desired workspace, and
- change the screen(s) back to the original workspaces,

that is a *lot* of effort.

I'm aware that one can force new windows with `--new-window` and new instances with `--standalone`, that would prevent opening new files in a tab in the "current" gedit window, which is behaviour I like.

How can I configure i3 and gedit so that there is one gedit window (or instance) per workspace?

Bonus points if it's possible to configure open actions on which workspace open a tab on which other workspace; that would be useful in multi-screen setups (file browser on one screen, associated editor on another).

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246827/geany-open-a-new-instance-per-workspace-when-opening-a-file-in-that-workspace)? Hard do tell, for me.

Comment: Can you not simply go the new workspace, and then launch gedit with the dmenu launcher? On my computer, that opens a new window...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos Opens a new tab in the last instance wherever for me. I can `Mod+D gedit -s`, of course, but that is far less convenient than double-clicking on the file in Thunar.